# talking to others at a gym

Tags: gym

I joined a gym at new year with a friend an we were going twice a week be he is becoming les interested with every visit and I found my self alone the other night.

Now while I quite enjoy the experience of the gym I found two hours of silence broken only by the sound of machines rather boring and feel the may lead to my giving up :(

There were lots of other people but they seemed content with the silence. So I was wondering is there rules about how to talk to others at the gym.
I mean I don't want to interrupt anyone else's workout but id like to strike up a conversation  is possible.

Comment: I'd suggest two hours is too long, perhaps you would be less likely to grow bored if you worked at a higher intensity or effort level for a shorter time. Personally, I would not be particularly able to talk and would much less want to when I am working out because my mind is focused on dealing with discomfort of whatever I'm doing. That said I do see people on machines reading and watching television quite happily, but I do think there is some value in pushing yourself past the ability to talk :). Headphones are a godsend too. Perhaps not the solipsist approach you're after..

Comment: @silasdavis when i joined the gym i got a hour with a personal trainer to set up a routing and he said that the easiest way to tell if you doing it right is that you should be able to hold a conversation that is broken by breathing

Comment: @SKeith - that is not true in all cases - it depends entirely on what type of workout you are going for. Some goals require you to almost be dropping through exhaustion by the end - others may allow you to easily hold a conversation.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone is different, but typically people go to the gym to work out, so - starting a conversation with someone while they are working out probably isn't a good approach.  You may want to 'initiate' a conversation with people after their workout or if you gym has group workout sessions (zumba for example or spinning classes) there...once again either just prior or post the workout.  I would suggest getting a music player of some sort to keep yourself entertained during your workout.....

Answer (score 2):

I have found a great conversation starter (and way to make friends at the gym) is asking someone for a spot or offering to give someone else a spot.